# Replace all bullets with spaces

Tags: bash

How can I replace bullets (octal value: 225, hexadecimal value: 95) with spaces?
I tried with the following commands:

```
echo '•test' | tr '\225' ' '

echo '•test' | awk '{gsub(/\225/," ");print $0}'

echo '•test' | sed 's/\o225/ /g'

echo '•test' | LANG='' sed 's/\o225/ /g'

echo '•test' | sed 's/\x95/ /g'
```

The above commands does not work.

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at why your current efforts are failing:

```
$ echo '•test' | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 a2 74 65 73 74 0a                           |...test.|
00000008
```

These bullets are actually three bytes -- `e2 80 a2`, not a single `0x95`.

A corrected sed expression works fine:

```
echo '•test' | sed -e 's/•/ /g'
```

...or (using bash-extended syntax not available in `/bin/sh`)...

```
echo '•test' | sed -e  $'s@\xe2\x80\xa2@ @g'
```

...or (using bash-builtin replacement functionality):

```
s='•test'             # original string in s
orig='•'              # item to replace
new=' '               # thing to replace it with
s2=${s//"$orig"/$new} # result in s2
```

...or (using GNU sed extensions, per @anubhava)...

```
echo '•test' | sed 's@\xe2\x80\xa2@ @g'
```

Comment: Or: `echo '•test' | sed 's/\xe2\x80\xa2/ /'`

Comment: Why do you use the at symbol (@)? I tested with the following command: echo '•test' | sed 's/\xe2\x80\xa2/ /g'. It works.

Comment: @user2874781, I use `@` as a matter of habit, because `/` exists often enough in content being replaced to make it a poor choice of sigil. In this particular case, neither exists, so it doesn't make a particular difference either way. (In many situations, the need to choose a sigil that can't be inside the data makes `sed` a poor choice of tools altogether).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch. For my own information, how in the hell did you know the OP was using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, I made a leap of faith that StackOverflow was representing their original content byte-for-byte, and looked at what they'd copied-and-pasted.

Comment: @anubhava: Not all `sed` implementations support `\xnn` escapes - works with _GNU_ sed, but not BSD/OSX `sed` for instance. POSIX `sed` only supports _basic_ regular expressions, according to which the sequence `\x` is _undefined_ - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03

Comment: @mklement0 Couldn't this be fixed by writing `$'s@\xe2\x80\xa2@ @g'` instead? The `$'...'` syntax will let the bash replace the `\x..` escape sequence before passing the string to `sed`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Absolutely, but that's already part of this answer (and comes with the already-mentioned caveat that it's a bash[/ksh/zsh]-ism).

Comment: @mklement0 I missed that part. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement of the excellent answer by Charles Duffy, the *bytes* corresponding to the *character* bullet might be different depending of the file encoding used.

As an example, the *bullet* is:

- the single byte `0x95` if the file is encoded as (Windows) CP1252
- the single byte `0xa5` if the file is encoded as (traditional) Macintosh Roman
  encoding
- a sequence of three bytes if the file is encoded as UTF-8

---

For "one byte encoding", `tr` was a good catch. As of myself, I would have favored a slightly different syntax, but that should work:

```
sh$ tr $'\x95' ' ' < cp1252.txt 
 test

sh$ tr $'\xa5' ' ' < mac.txt 
 test
```

If your file is UTF-8 encoded ... well you already have the answer!

Comment: +1: I didn't look up which encoding the `0x95` assumption came from, but it's useful background.